# What exactly is an "implicit search" and how does it work?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

In Coded UI, there are methods to wait for specific events during playback, for example `WaitForControlEnabled()` and `WaitForControlEnabled()`. According to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131072.aspx):

> All these methods have following behavior:
>
> - The methods return true if the wait is successful and false if the wait failed.
> - The implicit timeout for the wait operation is specified by WaitForReadyTimeout property. The default value of this property is 60000 milliseconds (one minute).
> - The methods have an overload to take explicit timeout in milliseconds. **However, when the wait operation results in an implicit search for the control or, when the application is busy, the actual wait time could be more than the timeout specified.**

My question is, what exactly is an "implicit search" and is it possible to disable it entirely, or have it shows up in the verbose log if it happens?

I cannot find an explanation for this in any official source. From my understanding, an implicit search is a search that will be carried out when the playback engine cannot find the exact UI control. However, it is different from `SmartMatch`, since even when I had disabled `SmartMatch`:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.None;
```

an implicit search still happened. I know this since I deliberately specified a non-exact value for a search property for an UI control and the control was still found. It took a very long time, and when I checked the verbose log there was no mention of `SmartMatch` nor was there any warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the expression `this.UIMap.UIOne.UITwo.UIThree`. To access the `UIThree` control needs `UITwo` to have been found and to find it needs `UIOne` to have been found. The finds of `UIOne` and `UITwo` are implicit finds.

An alternative is to write the statements:

```
this.UIMap.UIOne.Find();
this.UIMap.UIOne.UITwo.Find();
... this.UIMap.UIOne.UITwo.UIThree ...
```

The question states:

> From my understanding, an implicit search is a search that will be
>   carried out when the playback engine cannot find the exact UI control.

This is a wrong interpretation. The implicit search relates to finding the higher level controls in an expression with multiple properties chained by dots. When an exact match cannot be found then a smart match may be invoked. When an expression such as `this.UIMap.UIOne.UITwo.UIThree` is used then, potentially, smart matches may be used for each of the three controls.